# setup reticulate virtual environment with python 3.11.4

Tags: python, r, keras, reticulate

I have Python 3.11.4 installed. I have also installed `keras` package. I was trying to create a virtual environment but the command wants to install a new version of python (3.9). Is it possible to use the system-wide installed 3.11.4?

I tried:

```
install.packages("keras")
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = install_python())
```

and this pulls in and wants to install python 3.9. My question is simply if we can make the reticulate virtual environment to use python 3.11.4?

I am using Fedora 38 linux environment.

I tried:

```
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = NULL)
Error in stop_no_virtualenv_starter(version) : 
  Suitable Python installation for creating a venv not found.
Please install Python with one of following methods:
- https://github.com/rstudio/python-builds/
- reticulate::install_python(version = '<version>')
```

I also tried:

```
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = '/usr/lib/python3.11')
Error in stop_no_virtualenv_starter() : 
  Suitable Python installation for creating a venv not found.
Please install Python with one of following methods:
- https://github.com/rstudio/python-builds/
- reticulate::install_python(version = '<version>')
```

Thoguh I am not sure if my call is correct, because even the following did not work.

```
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = '/usr/lib/python3.11')
Error in stop_no_virtualenv_starter() : 
  Suitable Python installation for creating a venv not found.
Please install Python with one of following methods:
- https://github.com/rstudio/python-builds/
- reticulate::install_python(version = '<version>')
```

Per suggestion:

```
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = NULL, version='3.11')
Error in stop_no_virtualenv_starter(version) : 
  Suitable Python installation for creating a venv not found.
Requested version constraint: 3.11
Please install Python with one of following methods:
- https://github.com/rstudio/python-builds/
- reticulate::install_python(version = '<version>')
```

which python?

```
$ which python
python is /bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

Update: the issue continues even with the suggestions:

```
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = '/bin/python')
Error in stop_no_virtualenv_starter() : 
  Suitable Python installation for creating a venv not found.
Please install Python with one of following methods:
- https://github.com/rstudio/python-builds/
- reticulate::install_python(version = '<version>')
```

I do get:

```
 virtualenv_starter(version='3.11')
[1] "/usr/bin/python3.11"
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: And what happens when you pass `version = 3.11`?

Comment: So when your python path is: `/bin/python`, try to run: `virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = '/bin/python')` (If that is the version you want to use). Is `python3.11` in `/usr/lib/python3.11`?

Comment: Sorry, but it still does not work. See update above.

Comment: Assuming you're running the latest version of all the R packages, this should work. If it doesn't, please file an issue on GitHub. `keras::install_keras(python_version = "3.11")`. If you don't have python 3.11 installed, you can run `reticulate::install_python("3.11:latest")`.

Comment: Thanks, I do have the latest CRAN version of all packages. I will file on github.

Comment: I am using reticulate version 1.31. And the version number for python is indeed 3.11. (see update).

Comment: The issue was resolved on GitHub - needed to run `dnf install python3-pip` on Fedora